# Login form is protected against userscripts?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, autologin

Here is the login form from the site rutracker.org:

```html
<form id="top-login-form" action="http://login.rutracker.org/forum/login.php" method="post" style="display: inline;">
<input id="top-login-uname" type="text" placeholder="имя" accesskey="l" tabindex="1" name="login_username">
<input id="top-login-pwd" type="password" placeholder="пароль" tabindex="2" name="login_password">
<input id="top-login-btn" type="submit" tabindex="3" value="вход" name="login">
</form>
```

Here is the Greasemonkey script to autologin:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @include     http://rutracker.org/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var f = document.getElementById("top-login-form");
f.elements.namedItem("login_username").value = "xxxxxx";
f.elements.namedItem("login_password").value = "yyyyyyy";
f.elements.namedItem("login").value = "%E2%F5%EE%E4";
f.submit();
```

The problem is that only two values are actually sent, so the Post request is `login_username=xxxxxxx&login_password=yyyyyyy` insread of `login_username=xxxxxxx&login_password=yyyyyyy&login=%E2%F5%EE%E4`

So the `login=%E2%F5%EE%E4` is missing.

Is it some kind of protection against UserJS?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`login` is not a field, it's a button. You don't fill it - you click it. No need for `submit` too - it is implied by click.

```
f.elements.namedItem("login").click()
```

Comment: This solution works too, even better! Earlier, I had tried to use click in function as `waitForKeyElements ("input#top-login-btn", click1)` where 

`function click1 (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
`
It successfully clicked any other element but not this button. Have no idea why... Thank you, Oleg! / Спасибо, Олег! /

Answer (score 0):

> Is it some kind of protection against UserJS?

No.

When you submit a form, the clicked submit button is a successful control. Successful controls have their name and value included in the form data.

You are not submitting the form by clicking on a submit button. You are calling the `submit` method of the form object instead. Consequently, the submit button is not successful and its data is not included in the form.

> How can I solve this problem?

Replicate the name and value of the submit button in a hidden input.

Comment: I have shown the code of the button. It is `<input id="top-login-btn" type="submit" tabindex="3" value="вход" name="login">`. So I replicated it like this `f.elements.namedItem("login").value = "%E2%F5%EE%E4";` or like this `f.elements.namedItem("login").value = "вход";` - the result is the same. I actually submit the form as it is followed by redirection to the other page with recommendations to enable cookies and javascript to login.

Comment: @max5555 — Changing the value of the submit button won't help, it still won't be a successful control. You need to create a new, hidden input and copy the name and value from the submit button to it.

Comment: I added the field like this `$('#top-login-form').append('<input id="login_hidden" type="hidden" name="login" value="вход">');` and now the script working like a charm!!!! Thank you!!!!!!!